# Python sqlite => reportlab data what is difference between [1,2,3] and [[1],[2],[3]]

Tags: python, sqlite

I apologize in advance, but I just cannot figure it out....

I am attempting to read data from a sqlite database and populate data to a reportlab bar chart. The sample data that I have is a snippet from http://www.reportlab.com/snippets/3/

The sqlite3 code is:

```
def arrData():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('alarmdb.sqlite')
    ccursor = conn.cursor()
    strSQL = "Select distinct ErrorMsg, count(*) as Amt from tmpTable where cast(source as int)<20 group by ErrorMsg Order by count(*) desc limit 10"
    ccursor.execute(strSQL)
    arrResult = ccursor.fetchall()
    arrErrAmt = [int(element[1]) for element in arrResult]
    return arrErrAmt
```

but that returns [200, 100, 50, 40,..], but in the reportlab sample they show:
self.bar.data = [[4.22], [4.12], [3.65], [3.56], ...]

How do I do that with my arrData function?

Comment: oops i knew it was silly, I just added a bracket in the line below
    arrErrAmt = [int(element[1]) for element in arrResult]
 to make it
    arrErrAmt = [[int(element[1])] for element in arrResult]
sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element of the list `[[4.22], [4.12], [3.65], [3.56], ...]` is itself a list (containing one float).

Each element of the list `[200, 100, 50, 40,..]` is an int. So you need to create lots of lists instead of merely lots of ints.

You could change your code to:

```
[[int(element[1])] for element in arrResult]
```

or perhaps:

```
[[float(element[1])] for element in arrResult]
```

if you want it to look even more like the example data.